# percentage calculation based off total on cart page

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, php-5.4

I need advice on how to set this up. please refer to the image attached.

On the cart page I need to display 30% of the order total on the area marked with red circle called impact dollars. In other words if my order total is $100.00 the impact dollar section with automatically display $30.00 impact dollars.

I would also like to cary this %30 percent (impact dollars) to the confirmation page, to remind the user that out of their transaction had earned them a total or $30 impact dollars.

thanks

[image]

Comment: calculating a percentage of the cart total is very simple, but surely you need a system to track your "impact dollars" if I don't use them with this order they need to be stored and accumulated. That is more complex.